# Change Spelling Language on Google Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, language, spell-check

I use Google Chrome to write in UK English, most of the time. However, occasionally I need to write in US English. **How do I change spelling language in Google Chrome?**

Most advice on the Internet says that I should click 'Use this language for spell checking' in Language settings, but this option doesn't exist in my Chrome. See the below image, the top screenshot is from an article telling me to click 'Use this language for spell checking'. But this option doesn't exist in the lower screenshot, which is my install of Chrome:

[image: No language option]

I am using Chrome 50.0.2661.86 on OS X 10.11.4.

Comment: Which OS is in question, and which version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 updated the question, it is Chrome 50.0 and OS X 10.11.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1

Go to Mac OS **System Preferences** > **Language and region** > **Keyboard Preferences** > **Text**

There you can change the spelling option. And yes, you have British English ;)

### Solution 2

On **Chrome** > **Edit** > **Spelling & Grammar** > **Show Spelling & Grammar**

Comment: Okay, that fixed the issue. Although I did need to restart my Mac, so it's not ideal. Seems like very poor experience on part of Google and/or Apple, but I guess I am part of a small group that writes in two languages regularly.

Comment: No problem: check this: On **Chrome** > **Edit** > **Spelling & Grammar** > **Show Spelling & Grammar**

Comment: Thanks for that. Interestingly, when you select the language in the 'Spelling & Grammar' dialog box, it also changes the language for the 'Check as you type' functionality. Even when the dialog is closed. That completely solves my problem.